# Missing required parameters for [Route: profiles.edit] [URI: profiles/{user}/edit]. (View: D:\sites\eyiyce1\resources\views\profiles\show.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

This is my link

```
<a href="{{ route('profiles.edit', ['username' => $user->username]) }}" >Edit informations</a>
```

this is the error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: profiles.edit] [URI: profiles/{user}/edit]. (View: D:\sites\eyiyce1\resources\views\profiles\show.blade.php)

Please help me

Comment: Can you post the Route path from you `web.php` file that deals with this link.

Comment: i've resolv the issue.

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter is `user`, not `username`. Either change the link to

```
<a href="{{ route('profiles.edit', ['user' => $user]) }}" >Edit informations</a>
```

OR

change your route parameter to "username":

```
profiles/{username}/edit
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-parameters